# Why is my data not being fully concatenated?

Tags: python, string, graph, concatenation, shapes

I have daily electricity values taken every 2 minutes (timestamp column), for 3 different solar panel systems. (Timestamp column for the respective electricity generated at each time.) Each .csv sheet has 1 day's worth of data, so my file has x 18 months of that.

I want to get the average electricity generated for each of the systems at each timestamp. Final result should be a graph of electricity generated against timestamp.

My problem is that when i use .shape() to check that files were loaded into a dataframe, **the result printed was way too small - (588,8)**. 1 month's of excel sheets concatenated returned (4536,8). Not sure where it went wrong.

I tried the below code. Intention is to concatenate all the daily .csv files into one dataframe, then groupby. solar panel system and timestamp, then get average.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

excel_dir = '/kaggle/input/pv-output-1/PV 2122'

first_file = '/kaggle/input/pv-output-1/PV 2122/1 Apr 2021.csv'
PV_2122 = pd.read_csv(first_file)

for dirname, _, filenames in os.walk('/kaggle/input'):
    for filename in filenames:
        name = str(os.path.join(excel_dir, first_file))
    if name.endswith('.csv'):
        file_path = pd.read_csv(name)
        PV_2122 = pd.concat([file_path, PV_2122], ignore_index = True)

PV_2122.shape()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.